# Magento 2: RuntimeException it is being used by another process

Tags: magento2, module, cache, custom, exception

When I do clear cache using command line & refresh page on Frontend 1st time it gives below exception.

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (RuntimeException): The path
>   "D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session/Interceptor.php.6260"
>   cannot be renamed into
>   "D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session/Interceptor.php"
>   Warning!rename(D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session/Interceptor.php.6260,D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session/Interceptor.php):
>   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process. (code: 32)

When i refresh same page again/2nd time it loads page proper. What will be cause for above exception?

Comment: Did you find any stuff?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that while the `setup:di:compile` compilation process is running and Magento is processing requests (e.g. tries to bootstrap), this exception might appear.

Suggestion:

- enable maintenance mode
- stop cron processing
- deploy your changes (run compilation, static content deploy, etc)

From my perspective this is not a bug, but imperfect deploy process.

I will try to update the answer if I found out any more details.

Answer (score 0):

Improper deployment process leads to this kind of error, just remove all the files from var/generation folder and run a setup:upgrade command, this issue must be resolved after this.This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove everything from var/generation folder, and execute that commands: 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
if you still get the error please check var/exception.log for more informations