# Magento 2: Runtime Exception

Tags: magento2, cache, exception, runtime

I got below error on my Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0 on WAMP

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (RuntimeException): The path "D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Config/Model/ResourceModel/Config/Data/Collection/Proxy.php.5756" cannot be renamed into "D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Config/Model/ResourceModel/Config/Data/Collection/Proxy.php" Warning!rename(D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Config/Model/ResourceModel/Config/Data/Collection/Proxy.php.5756,D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Config/Model/ResourceModel/Config/Data/Collection/Proxy.php): The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (code: 32)

Exception #0 (RuntimeException): The path "D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Config/Model/ResourceModel/Config/Data/Collection/Proxy.php.5756" cannot be renamed into "D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Config/Model/ResourceModel/Config/Data/Collection/Proxy.php" Warning!rename(D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Config/Model/ResourceModel/Config/Data/Collection/Proxy.php.5756,D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Config/Model/ResourceModel/Config/Data/Collection/Proxy.php): The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (code: 32)
#0 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\Config\\...')
#1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\\Config\\...')
#2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\\Config\\...')
#3 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime.php(38): class_exists('Magento\\Config\\...')
#4 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Config\Config.php(153): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime->has('Magento\\Config\\...')
#5 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Config\Config.php(176): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->_inheritInterception('Magento\\Config\\...')
#6 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\ObjectManager\Config\Developer.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->hasPlugins('Magento\\Config\\...')
#7 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(70): Magento\Framework\Interception\ObjectManager\Config\Developer->getInstanceType('Magento\\Config\\...')
#8 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Config\\...')
#9 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Config\\...')
#10 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'resourceCollect...', 'Magento\\Config\\...')
#11 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Config\\...', Array, Array)
#12 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Config\\...', Array)
#13 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\Data\ProcessorFactory.php(41): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Config\\...')
#14 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\MetadataProcessor.php(85): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Data\ProcessorFactory->get('Magento\\Config\\...')
#15 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\Data.php(33): Magento\Framework\App\Config\MetadataProcessor->process(Array)
#16 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Data->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\MetadataProcessor), Array)
#17 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#18 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#19 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\DataFactory.php(46): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#20 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\ScopePool.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\Config\DataFactory->create(Array)
#21 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Config.php(41): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopePool->getScope('default', NULL)
#22 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver.php(82): Magento\Backend\App\Config->getValue('admin/url/use_c...')
#23 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\module-backend\Helper\Data.php(206): Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver->getFrontName(false)
#24 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor.php(46): Magento\Backend\Helper\Data->getAreaFrontName()
#25 D:\wamp\www\magento2\var\generation\Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), '/customer/accou...')
#26 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Request\Http.php(165): Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), '/customer/accou...')
#27 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request.php(209): Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->setPathInfo()
#28 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Request\Http.php(208): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request->getPathInfo()
#29 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(130): Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->getFrontName()
#30 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#31 D:\wamp\www\magento2\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#32 {main}
```

When i refresh that page it goes. Would like to know root cause of this exeception & how to solve it?

Comment: Duplicate of question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136445/magento-2-runtimeexception-it-is-being-used-by-another-process